# Solve the system of linear equations for all values of a

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

When solving the following matrix for $a$:
$$ \left[ 
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  x&2y&az&3\\
  (2a-4)x&(2-a)y&(-2a+4)z&0\\
  4x&4y&2az&8
\end{array}
\right]
$$

When do I put restrictions on which values $a$ can take? Say I divide the second row by $(2-a)$, does this mean that $a$ cannot be 2, or can I only say something like that when the entire matrix is in row echelon form, and I would be left with something like:
$$ \left[ 
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1&0&0&\frac{2a}{a-2}\\
  0&1&0&\frac{4-5a}{a-2}\\
  0&0&1&\frac{a^2}{a-2}
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Comment: The method is fine but when you divide by $a-2$ you are assuming that $a\neq2$ thus the solution is valid within this limitation. To conlcude you need to verify the case a=2 in the original system and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't check the detail of calculation but, if it is correct, the solution you have found is valid for $a\neq 2$ (i.e. the system has exactly a solution $\forall a\neq2$).

Now you need also to verify the solution/s for the case $a=2$ in the original system, that is

$$\left[ 
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1&2&2&3\\
  4&4&4&8
\end{array}
\right]\implies \left[ 
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1&2&2&3\\
  1&1&1&2
\end{array}
\right]\implies \left[ 
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1&2&2&3\\
  0&1&1&1
\end{array}
\right]\implies\left[ 
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1&0&0&1\\
  0&1&1&1
\end{array}
\right]$$
thus for a=2 the system has infinitely many solutions

- $x=1$
- $y+z=1$

Comment: And if I would encounter a division by something with an $a$ while working towards row echelon form, do I also have to check it in that case, or only for a division by $a$ that is present in the final row echelon form?

Comment: @B.E This is a rule valid in a widely context. When divide for a quantity we are implicitely setting a condition that this quantity is $\neq 0$ thus if in the process you divide also for a the final solution is valido for $a\neq 0$ (and $a\neq 2$).

Answer (score 1):

from the first and the last equation we get $$x=1$$(after dividing the third equation by $4$
then we get
$$2y+az=2$$
and
$$(2-a)y+(4-2a)z=4-2a$$
with $$y=\frac{2-az}{2}$$ we get
$$\frac{2-a}{2}(2-az)+(4-2a)z=4-2a$$
can you finish?
the last equation is equivalent to $$1/2\, \left( a-2 \right)  \left( az-4\,z+2 \right)=0$$

Comment: So, $x=1$, $y=\frac{2-az}{2}$, $z=\frac{6}{a+4}$? $(2-az)\frac{2-a}{2}+(-2a+4)z=-2a+4$ --> $\frac{1}{2}(a-2)(2-az)-2(a-2)z=-2(a-2)$ --> $-\frac{1}{4}(2-az)+z=1$ --> $2-az-4z=-4$ --> $az+4z=6$ --> $z = \frac{6}{a+4}$